# Combine Row()'s in Spark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Seemingly simple question, but can't find the answer.

Problem: I create a function that I will pass into map() that takes a single field and creates three fields out of it. I want the output of the map() to give me a new RDD, including both the fields from the input RDD and the new/output RDD. How do I do this?

Do I need to add the key of my data into the output of the function so that I can join more output RDD back to my original RDD? Is that the proper/best practice?

```
def extract_fund_code_from_iv_id(holding):
    # Must include key of data for later joining
    iv_id = Row(iv_id_fund_code=holding.iv_id[:2], iv_id_last_code=holding.iv_id[-2:])
    return iv_id
```

Even more basic, I can't seem to combine two Row's.

```
row1 = Row(name="joe", age="35")
row2 = Row(state="MA")
print row1, row2
```

This doesn't return a new Row() like I want it to.

Thanks

Comment: `print` will of course output a string representation of your objects and not create a new `Row` instance. As to your first question, you might want to look into Spark's DataFrame API (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame) and maybe you'll find the User Defined Function iteresting

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have used the user-defined functions options which are pretty powerful however not able to do what I need which forced me to use a RDD. I don't see any options of how to combine Row RDD...

Comment: The issue is that when I run a .map() method on the DataFrame it returns a new RDD, but I need it to return the new RDD with the old columns, and I don't want to write some ugly code to discover what the column names are in the RDD and then write it. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7):

I would really recommend using `UserDefinedFunction`.

Suppose you wanted to extract a number of features from a column `int_col` of type `int` of a DataFrame `df`. Let's say these features are simply `modulo 3` and `modulo 2` of said column content.

We'll import `UserDefinedFunction` and the data type of our functions.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
```

Then we'll implement our feature extraction functions:

```
def modulo_three(col):
    return int(col) % 3

def modulo_two(col):
    return int(col) % 2
```

and turn them into `udf`s:

```
mod3 = udf(modulo_three, IntegerType())
mod2 = udf(modulo_two, IntegerType())
```

Now we'll compute all additional columns and give them nice names (via `alias`):

```
new_columns = [
    mod3(df['int_col']).alias('mod3'),
    mod2(df['int_col']).alias('mod2'),
]
```

Finally we select these columns plus all columns that already existed before:

```
new_df = df.select(*df.columns+new_columns)
```

`new_df` will now have two additional columns `mod3` and `mod2`.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you so much for taking the time!